# PHP string not building

Tags: php, string

I have the following code to iterate through an array and build a string from the results:

```
$finalstring;
$tempstring;

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
     $i = 0;
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        $i+= 1;

        if($i == 1)
        {           

            $tempstring . $value1 . "|";

        }
        if($i == 2)
        {   

            $tempstring . $value1 . "|||||";

        }
        if($i == 3)
        {   

            $tempstring  . $value1 . "||||||||||";

        }
        if($i == 4)
        {    

            $tempstring  . $value1 . "|||||||||||||||||\n";

        }

    }

            echo $tempstring;
            $finalstring . $tempstring;

}
            echo $finalstring;
```

However, the code seems to not be building a string (The array is definitely not empty, and it formatted like so-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ron
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => Boss
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Tim
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => player
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jim
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => manager
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Lud
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => employee
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ron
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => sub boss
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Lev
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => mini boss
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Timpthy
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => super boss
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jimbo
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => final battle
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Name] => El
            [Date] => 9/23/10
            [Title] => link
            [Activity] => Soccer
        )

)
```

Is there any reason why the code is failing to build both `$tempstring` and `$finalstring` (by this i mean that the echo statements are not outputting a value)?

Comment: $tempstring .= [...] ?

Comment: You're never assigning the value anywhere. you need: `$tempstring .= $value1 . "|";`

Comment: It's building just fine, you're just never doing anything with the resulting value.

Comment: You are not storing your string anywhere. You need to assign your values to $tempstring like this: $tempstring .= $value1.'|';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should build it like this:

```
$tempstring .= $value1 . "|";
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you are doing this, but the error is that you are failing to assign the concatenated value. As it is, the concatenation result is not going anywhere, even if it is calculated (not sure if it's even evaluated since I suspect the interpreter has optimizations built in that would just ignore the evaluation altogether)

Instead of:

```
$tempstring . $value1 . "|";
```

You should write:

```
$tempstring .= $value1 . "|";
```

Or in longhand:

```
$tempstring = $tempstring . $value1 . "|";
```

Answer (score 1):

initialized the `$finalstring` and `$tempstring` as empty string. And each time you want to store the value to the variable, use this for example

```
$tempstring .= $value1 . "|";
```

remember to put `=` so the value can merge